WFS query that always returns numberOfFeatures="0" no matter what bbox is used
I'm running a GetFeature WFS query using the parameter resultType to get the number of features in the extent comprised in the bbox parameter.
However I always get 0 as the number of features, even if I keep changing the bbox (and I'm pretty sure there are features in that extent).
The query is the following : QUERY

You are making a WFS 1.0.0 GetFeature request. The optional parameter &resultType=results/hits was introduced in WFS 1.1.0.
So the resultType=hits does not need to work with WFS 1.0.0. However, with that server resultType=hits does work somehow also with WFS 1.0.0. Servers are allowed to support additional features "vendor options", but in that case it would be nice if they work as supposed. With that server it is not the case. The resultType=hits shows zero hits, but resultType=results return lots of results.
The resultType parameter does work if you change the service version into WFS 1.1.0. You must swithch the coordinates of the bounding box by the same into lat-lon order.
https://data.geopf.fr/wfs/ows?SERVICE=WFS&VERSION=1.1.0&REQUEST=GetFeature&typeName=BDTOPO_V3:batiment&bbox=48.80,2.24,48.90,2.43&resultType=hits
...numberOfFeatures="5000"...

In WFS 1.1.0 numberOfFeatures reports how many features a request with &resultType=results would return. It the server has a feature count limit, like this server, it reports that count (5000).
In WFS 2.0.0 the behavior of resultType was changed and a new parameter numberMatched reports the total number of feature which match the query. If the server has count limit, this means that the whole resultset must be fetched with several requests.
https://data.geopf.fr/wfs/ows?SERVICE=WFS&VERSION=2.0.0&REQUEST=GetFeature&typeName=BDTOPO_V3:batiment&bbox=48.80,2.24,48.90,2.43&resultType=hits
numberMatched="220758"
...


It is working just as you described. However, there are more than 5000 features in that extent so I imagine the server returned only the maximum number that it can actually send per request (5000). I changed the version to 2.0.0 and I got numberMatched="220758", which is actually what I'm looking for!

Right, I edited my answer and added also a WFS 2.0.0 example.
